# run c++ function in angularjs

Tags: c++, angularjs

I developed an application in C++ recently. Now I want to make the front end in AngularJS (the application involves searching the database, and the results of the C++ program will be stored in a file, output.txt).

My question is as follows. How do I run the C++ program in AngularJS?

Comment: serve the response from your other application over http to the AngularJS client

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: You cannot run a c++ application in a user's browser. For instance, when the user clicks a button, you need to send a (http) request to your web server, execute your c++ application there and response whatever the result of that application is. How the server handles the request depends a bit on your server and your main language there. It might be an option to reengineer your c++ application in a script language like PHP, Python, Ruby or direct in JavaScript.